# html-pdf package is not working on aws lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers, html-pdf, node-html-pdf

I have tried implementing **html-pdf** package in my code which is deployed at **AWS lambda** but getting error in it even after I have deployed the **layer** for html-pdf package at lambda.
Below is my code:

```
import pdf from 'html-pdf';
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

var S3 = new AWS.S3();
process.env.PATH = `${process.env.PATH}:/opt`;
process.env.FONTCONFIG_PATH = "/opt";
process.env.LD_LIBRARY_PATH = "/opt";

export const convertToPDFandUpload = async (attachmentFile, empCertificate) => {
    let file;
    let params;
    var options = {
        height: "590px",
        width: "800px",
        phantomPath: '/opt/phantomjs_linux-x86_64'
    };

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        pdf.create(attachmentFile, options).toBuffer(function (err, res) {
            if (err)
                console.log(err);
            file = res;
            params = {
                Bucket: <my_bucket_name>,
                Key: `certificate/${empCertificate.candidateName}${empCertificate.certificateID}.pdf`,
                Body: file,
                ACL: 'public-read'
            };
            S3.upload(params, async function (err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err, err.stack);
                    reject(null);
                } else {
                    resolve(data.Location);
                }
            });
        });
    });
};
```

It is throwing an error after toBuffer() function.

Error:
{
"errorType": "TypeError",
"errorMessage": "Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined",
"stack": [
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined",
"    at execPdfToBuffer (/var/task/apis/webpack:/home/nikhilsrivastva/Desktop/HR Onboarding/onboarding BE/hronboardingcodebase/services/certification/node_modules/html-pdf/lib/pdf.js:48:1)",
"    at ChildProcess.respond (/var/task/apis/webpack:/home/nikhilsrivastva/Desktop/HR Onboarding/onboarding BE/hronboardingcodebase/services/certification/node_modules/html-pdf/lib/pdf.js:144:1)",
"    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)",
"    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)",
"    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:276:12)"
]
}

Comment: What does the structure of your layer zip file look like?  Does it contain a folder named nodejs which contains a folder named node_modules?

Answer (score 0):

In the options, set `localUrlAccess: true` , I got the same issue, and this resolved it.

```js
var options = {
  height: "590px",
  width: "800px",
  phantomPath: '/opt/phantomjs_linux-x86_64',
  localUrlAccess: true
};
```

Answer (score -1):

The layer zip file must contain a folder named "nodejs" and that folder must contain the "node_modules" folder that has your dependencies. View the exact structure here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-path

> Example file structure for the AWS X-Ray SDK for Node.js
>
> ```
> `xray-sdk.zip 
>     └ nodejs/node_modules/aws-xray-sdk`
> ```

So you can verify that your layer zip file has the right structure.