# Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined Using html-pdf with lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I'm experiencing problems when I try to create a PDF from HTML using Lambda Function, I'm receiving the error below:

```
{
    "errorType": "TypeError",
    "errorMessage": "Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined",
    "trace": [
        "TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined",
        "    at execPdfToBuffer (/var/task/node_modules/html-pdf/lib/pdf.js:48:21)",
        "    at ChildProcess.respond (/var/task/node_modules/html-pdf/lib/pdf.js:144:5)",
        "    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)",
        "    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)",
        "    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:276:12)"
    ]
}
```

My code is:

```
try{
    
    let arq = await new Promise((res,rej)=>{
      pdf.create(html,{
        format: "Letter",
        orientation: "portrait",
        phantomPath: '/opt/phantomjs_linux-x86_64'
      }).toBuffer(function(err, buffer){
        if (err){
          rej(false);
        }else{
          res(buffer);
        } 
      });
    });

    const params = {
      Key: 'teste.pdf',
      Body: arq, // <---------
      Bucket: 'temp'
    };
    
    let S3 = new AWS.S3();
    let response = await S3.upload(params).promise();
    
    if (response){
      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    }

  }catch(err){
    console.log(err);
    return false;
  }
```

I've read this topic: [html-pdf package is not working on aws lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67776735/html-pdf-package-is-not-working-on-aws-lambda)
But the proposed solution didn't work for me.

Thank you in advance

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined", at execPdfToBuffer` suggests that `pdf.create()` is not passing a PDF object to `.toBuffer()`, but rather an `undefined` - test the return type and investigate why your PDF creation is failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the version 3.0.1 you can set the flag  localUrlAccess: true, , it will work

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue, too. I fixed it by downgrading `html-pdf` from version `3.0.1` to version `2.2.0`.

The [release notes](https://github.com/marcbachmann/node-html-pdf/releases/tag/v3.0.0) for the newer version are less than inspiring: "Not sure this module is even usable without installing phantomjs manually"

Perhaps there's a way to make version 3 work with lambda. But downgrading was a quick win for me.

Comment: set the flag  localUrlAccess: true, worked for me in version 3.0.1